# Doing case-by-case proofs about match statements in Lean4

Tags: lean4, tactic, proof-review, pattern-matching

In Lean4, I am stuck in a proof with a goal like this:

```
⊢ (match
    match a :: b with
    | [] => []
    | [x] => [x]
    | x :: xs => x :: [delim] :: intersperse [delim] xs with
  | [] => []
  | a :: as => a ++ join as) =
  delim :: tail
```

Intuitively to me I would prove this by doing a case-by case analysis of the inner match statement. In other words,  I would expect some tactic that would generate three subgoals:

1. Add `a :: b = []` as an additional hypothesis, goal of

```
⊢ (match []
  | [] => []
  | a :: as => a ++ join as) =
  delim :: tail
```

2. Add `a :: b = [x]` as an additional hypothesis, goal of

```
⊢ (match [x]
  | [] => []
  | a :: as => a ++ join as) =
  delim :: tail
```

3. Add `a :: b = x :: xs` as an additional hypothesis$,^\dagger$  goal of

```
⊢ (match x :: [delim] :: intersperse [delim] xs
  | [] => []
  | a :: as => a ++ join as) =
  delim :: tail
```

Here's a list of some things I have tried to solve this.

1. The `split` tactic seems to split the outer match rather than the inner match, and it doesn't name any of the hypotheses, which makes it impossible to continue the proof. I can't seem to figure out any way to modify this behavior.
2. Using the `cases` tactic on the expression being matched: `cases h₂: a::b with | nil => ... | cons a b | => ...`.  This does successfully do a case split based on the value of the match expression, but it splits it into the `nil` and `cons` cases, rather than the three arms of the match.
3. I attempted to construct a toy problem to experiment with: `theorem foo (a:α) (b:List α) (P: b ≠ []): (match a :: b with | [] => [] | [x] => [x] | x :: xs => c) =  c`.  I thought that this theorem would require a case by case analysis, but it turns out `simp` just solved it!  When I look at `simp?`'s output, it says `Try this: simp only [split_match.match_1.eq_3]`, but the theorem `split_match.match_1.eq_3` doesn't seem to actually exist if I try to use it:

```
invalid field notation, type is not of the form (C ...) where C is a constant
  split_match.match_1
has type
  (motive : List ?m.36429 → Sort ?u.36427) →
    (x : List ?m.36429) →
      (Unit → motive []) →
        ((x : ?m.36429) → motive [x]) → ((x : ?m.36429) → (xs : List ?m.36429) → motive (x :: xs)) → motive x
```

$\dagger$ I think this hypothesis could be even stronger because we know it didn't match the second case, but I'm not worried about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, this my not be the most optimal answer, but here is how I would approach this.

Also, note, it is important to provide a MWE when you ask questions like this so that the answerer can plug this into Lean themselves and make sure their answer works.  I'm using your `foo` as my MWE.

All three of your approaches work for `foo` and you should be able to modify them for your original goal.

1. `split`.  If you want to split by the match statement cases, then yes, I believe this is the way to go.  (I'm not sure about splitting by just the inner match.  There probably is a way, but the easiest is just to split on the outer match first and then split on the inner match.)  You mentioned that the variables are not named.  The trick to `split` (and `cases` and `induction`) is that you can name the hypotheses yourself like follows:

   ```
   theorem foo (a:α) (b:List α) (P: b ≠ []):
       (match a :: b with | [] => [] | [x] => [x] | x :: xs => c) = c := by
     split  -- split into three cases
     . case h_1 b' h => contradiction -- this case is impossible and obviously so
     . case h_2 b' a' h =>
       -- this case is impossible, but needs some work to show
       cases b -- split on if b is nil or not
       . case nil => contradiction
       . case cons a'' b'' =>
         apply absurd h  -- just need to show that h is false
         simp
     . case h_3 b' a' b'' h1 h2 => rfl  -- the goal is just c = c
   ```

   The name after each `case` just comes from what Lean names the goals.  As for naming the variables, I just spam a bunch of variable names like `a'` `b'` `c'` ..., and then see what they become in the goal.  I go back and clean it up, renaming them to useful names.  If you don't need a variable, you can leave it out (if at the end of the list) or name it `_`.

   Also note that all but one of the three cases was impossible.  So I just had to use the `contradiction` tactic to solve the subgoal.  The second case was a bit more tricky, so I did `cases` on `b` to prove the hypotheses were inconsistent.
2. `cases` (or `induction` in some settings).  I would actually recommend this.  In this example, and your original use case, most of the match cases can't be reached.  It is therefore easier to reason about the objects you are putting into `match` than the cases of `match`.  For example:

   ```
   theorem foo1 (a:α) (b:List α) (P: b ≠ []):
       (match a :: b with | [] => [] | [x] => [x] | x :: xs => c) = c := by
     cases b
     . case nil => contradiction
     . case cons a' b' => rfl
   ```

   Notice, this proof is much shorter.  Also, notice I'm doing `cases`/`induction` on `b` and not `a :: b`.
3. `simp` When `simp` works it is great.  Note that in Lean 4, `simp` will automatically generate lemmas like the ones you saw, which is why they are not visible to you when you don't use `simp`.  It is different in Lean 3 where the lemmas are generated automatically whether you call `simp` or not, and I saw some discussion of making it possible to add an option have these automatically generated from the start in Lean 4.